# How can I hide or scrolling my fixed social sidebar when it reaches to the footer part?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make my social sidebar in the left side scrolling or hide when it will reach to the footer part. So how can I do it please ? Thanks.

Comment: are you requesting ajax calls on page load?

Comment: I think your javascript is working fine; but due to iframe request for comments, left sidebar height is not equal to main block height. You need to reset the left sidebar height again after iframe request complete.

Comment: Yes, is it making any problem ? And how can I reset the height of the sidebar @Aboodred1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the floating social bar on the left to hide when an element i.e. the footer, is visible within the viewport of the browser, you can compare the top offset of the element with the bottom position of the browser's viewport. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).scroll(function(){

    var footerSelector = '#wrapper-12';
    var socialBarSelector = '.pw-float-left';

    var bottomViewPort = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
    var footerTop = $(footerSelector ).offset().top;

    if( bottomViewPort>=footerTop){
      $(socialBarSelector).fadeOut();
    }else{
      $(socialBarSelector).fadeIn();
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks a lot.... Actaully I have forgot about the fadeOut and fadeIn function.

Comment: @user2361994  i believe the answer meets your needs so please mark it as accepted in order to help other visitors as well, thanks